# Bash ignore commands, other options not working

Tags: bash

Prefacing a command with a space is not making bash not save it to history.  This is in my `.bash_profile`

`HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth`

What else do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your line to your `~/.bashrc`.